# Why can't I knit my R Markdown document even though other RMD files work just fine?

Tags: r, statistics, r-markdown, knitr

So I've been doing some R exercises for uni, and one thing that was good to have is a knitted document of your R execution.
Two semesters later, I'm once again doing R exercises. And again, I'm trying to have my knitted document at the end. I used an Rmd template as usual, my code and everything works fine. But when I knit, I get the error below.
The strange thing is that when I try to knit the Rmd files from two semesters ago, it still works. Only this current Rmd file doesn't want to be knitted.
What to do to fix this?

Error message:

```
Fehler in png(..., res = dpi, units = "in") : 
  kann png()-Gerät nicht starten
Ruft auf: <Anonymous> ... in_dir -> plot2dev -> do.call -> <Anonymous> -> png
Zusätzlich: Warnmeldungen:
1: In dir.create(dirname(name), recursive = TRUE) :
  kann Verzeichnis 'Empirical-Research-Lab-1---Descriptive-Statistics-2_files' nicht erzeugen, Grund 'No such file or directory'
2: In png(..., res = dpi, units = "in") :
  kann Datei 'Empirical-Research-Lab-1---Descriptive-Statistics-2_files/figure-html/unnamed-chunk-4-1.png' nicht zum Schreiben öffnen
3: In png(..., res = dpi, units = "in") : opening device failed
```

Translation:

```
Error in png(..., res = dpi, units = "in") : 
  cannot start png() device
Calls: <Anonymous> ... in_dir -> plot2dev -> do.call -> <Anonymous> -> png
Additionally: warnings:
1: In dir.create(dirname(name), recursive = TRUE) :
  cannot create directory 'Empirical-Research-Lab-1---Descriptive-Statistics-2_files', reason 'No such file or directory'
2: In png(..., res = dpi, units = "in") :
  cannot open file 'Empirical-Research-Lab-1---Descriptive-Statistics-2_files/figure-html/unnamed-chunk-4-1.png' in write mode
3: In png(..., res = dpi, units = "in") : opening device failed
```

[image: Error message upon knitting]

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: @r2evans I included the error output now

Comment: Sorry, but you should include an english translation of the error.

Comment: @Onyambu Ok, so someone edited it with a translation now

Comment: You should have shown the code where the error is. Ensure that when putting the image using png, the path of the image is provided. Or the image is in the working directory of the markdown

Comment: In your screenshot it doesn't show where you are using the `png()`, which is what the error is referencing. You need to check your `png()` function and move the file it's loading into the same directory as the .Rmd file

Comment: @DanielJachetta  But I didn't use any png() function, I searched for it with "Find" as well, no occurences for "png" at all..

Comment: upload a screenshot of code lines 70-100 so we can see where the error is according to Rstudio. Thank you